# How to compare sentence character by character in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-comparison

I want to write a code to count number of words in a given sentence by using character comparison and below is the code I have written as I am not allowed to use some fancy utilities like split(), etc. So, could you please guide me where am I making mistakes' I am a novice in python and currently trying to fiigure out how to do charactery by character comparison so as to find out simple counts of words, lines, strings withous using built in utitilites. So, kindly guide me about it.

Input Sentence : I am XYZ

```
Input_Sentence = raw_input("Enter your sentence: ")
print Input_Sentence
count = 0
i=0
while(Input_Sentence[i] != "\n"):
    if(Input_Sentence[i] == ' '):
        count=count+1
        i+=1
    else:
        i+=1
print ('Number of Words in a given sentence is :'      +str(count))
```

Comment: What does it output, what is the error? [You are not indexing `Input_Sentence` in your while condition - presume you meant `Input_Sentence[i]`]

Comment: Thanks , Edited it

Comment: And, does it work?

Comment: So what is the issue you are having?

Comment: No, It is giving IndexError: string index out of range error

Comment: if(Input_Sentence[i] == ' '): is giving error of string index out of range

Comment: You cannot use the check for `\n` in `while`. `Input_Sentence` does not contain a newline. You can use for example: `while i < len(Input_Sentence)`. And yes, see the answer: for loop is better here.

Answer (score 3):

At first I wouldn't use a while loop in this context. Why not using a for loop?

```
for char in Input_sentence:
```

With this you iterate over every letter.
Then you can use the rest of you code and check:

```
if char == ' ':
```

Comment: Better not use `i` in the for loop. It's not an index, it's a character. This will confuse newbie readers.

Comment: You are right. I was simply using the given code. I've modified my answer a bit and hope it is now clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
# initialize the counter
word_count = 0

last_space_index = 0    

# loop through each character in the sentence (assuming Input_Sentence is a string)
for i, x in enumerate(Input_Sentence):  # enumerate to get the index of the character
    # if a space is found (or newline character for end of sentence)
    if x in (' ', '\n'):
        word_count += 1  # increment the counter
        last_space_index = i  # set the index of the last space found

if len(Input_Sentence) > (last_space_index + 1):  # check if we are at the end of the sentence (this is in case the word does not end with a newline character or a space)
    word_count += 1

# print the total number of words
print 'Number of words:', word_count
```

Comment: This counts spaces and newlines in the input. For some examples this is the same as the word count.

Comment: Thanks. But, it is showing word_count =2 for sentence : I am XYZ.

Comment: @user2878667 that is a problem with the program logic you presented, not just this answer. What happens when a string does not end in a space?

Comment: @user2878667 I have updated my answer to work with your example. It should work whether you have a newline character at the end of the sentence or not.

Answer (score 0):

The following will avoid errors if there's an space at the beginning or the end of the sentence.

```
Input_Sentence = raw_input("Enter your sentence: ")
print Input_Sentence

count = 0
sentence_length = len(Input_Sentence)
for i in range(sentence_length):
    if Input_Sentence[i] == " ":
        if i not in (0, sentence_length - 1):
            count += 1
count += 1
print "There are %s words in the sentence \"%s\"." % (count, Input_Sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use try-except syntax.

In your code you used `while(Input_Sentence[i] != "\n")` to find when the sentence comes to an end. If you just print the output at every step before `i+ = 1` like this:

```
...
while(Input_Sentence[i] != "\n"):
   ...
        print i,Input_Sentence[i]
        i+=1
    else:
        print i,Input_Sentence[i],'*'
        i+=1
...
```

you can see for yourself that the output is something like this:

```
Enter your sentence: Python is good     
Python is good
0 P *
1 y *
2 t *
3 h *
4 o *
5 n *
6  
7 i *
8 s *
9  
10 g *
11 o *
12 o *
13 d *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog8.py", line 19, in <module>
    while(Input_Sentence[i] != "\n"):
IndexError: string index out of range
```

which means that the code that you have written works fine upto the length of the input sentence. After that when `i` is increased by 1 and it is demanded of the code to check if `Input_Sentence[i] == "\n"` it gives `IndexError`. This problem can be overcome by using exception handling tools of Python. Which leaves the option to neglect the block inside `try` if it is an exception and execute the block within `except` instead.

```
Input_Sentence = raw_input("Enter your sentence: ")
print Input_Sentence
count = 0
i=0
try:
    while (Input_Sentence[i] != "\n"):
        if (Input_Sentence[i] == ' '):
            count=count+1
            i+=1
        else:
            i+=1
except:
    count = count+1
    print ('Number of Words in a given sentence is :'      +str(count))
```